# How to inject CSS in document.writes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a some kind of Reservation-Review. How can I put on some designs and alignments in this code. I have tried putting it in a div but still doesn't work. Is there any way on how will I be able to do this?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
body{
    font-family:metro normal;
    font-size:30px;
} 

</style>

<script>

    // Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {
            var SelectCountry = localStorage.getItem("SelectCountry");
            var SelectTime = localStorage.getItem("SelectTime");
    var datepicker = localStorage.getItem("datepicker");
        var Persons = localStorage.getItem("Persons");

            document.write("Branch: \r\n"  +SelectCountry);
        document.write(" \r\nTime: " +SelectTime);
        document.write(" \r\nDate: " +datepicker);

            if (Persons !== null){
             document.write(" \r\nPersons: " +Persons);

                }
        }


</script>
</head>    

<body onload = "init();">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are calling [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after document ready which removed the current document completely.

so remove the onload handler and

```
function init() {
    var SelectCountry = localStorage.getItem("SelectCountry");
    var SelectTime = localStorage.getItem("SelectTime");
    var datepicker = localStorage.getItem("datepicker");
    var Persons = localStorage.getItem("Persons");

    //document.write('<style>body {color: red;}</style>');

    document.write("Branch: \r\n" + SelectCountry);
    document.write(" \r\nTime: " + SelectTime);
    document.write(" \r\nDate: " + datepicker);

    if (Persons !== null) {
        document.write(" \r\nPersons: " + Persons);

    }
}
init();
```

Note: Try using dom element modification instead of using document.write like

```
// Called on body's `onload` event
function init() {
    var SelectCountry = localStorage.getItem("SelectCountry");
    var SelectTime = localStorage.getItem("SelectTime");
    var datepicker = localStorage.getItem("datepicker");
    var Persons = localStorage.getItem("Persons");

    var html = "Branch: \r\n" + SelectCountry;
    html += " \r\nTime: " + SelectTime;
    html += " \r\nDate: " + datepicker;

    if (Persons !== null) {
        html += " \r\nPersons: " + Persons;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
```

then

```
<body onload = "init();">
```

Comment: Instead of string concatenation push stuff into an array and join afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the text to be written in the body, but in a specific `div`... right?

If so, then instead of

```
document.writy("text")
```

you could use this Javascript

```
document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv').innerHTML="text"
```

or, with jQuery:

```
$("#idOfTheDiv").html("text")
```

Hope it helps you.